# Show that every finite directed acyclic graph has at least one source vertex

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory

> Easy puzzle courtesy of a paper I'm reading rn:
>
> Show that every finite directed acyclic graph has at least one source vertex. That is, a vertex such that all the directed edges incident to it are directed away from said vertex.

The above is the exact text from a [post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1923323131245618/permalink/3255697664674818/) on the Facebook group: "Actually good maths problems".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't much of a puzzle?

> Start at any vertex, and repeatedly follow arrows backwards as long as you can. Once you cannot follow any arrows backwards, you're done.
>
>  This process will terminate in finite time, because if it ever ended up at the same vertex again, the edges travelled would create a cycle.